# Is it femto-photography or pico-photography?

Tags: terminology, laser

In several online resources I see a mention of femto-photography but when I read or view a video I hear about events measured on a pico-second scale. I am wondering about the reason for the naming convention. Can you give reference for established highest or near high frame rate.

In [this article](https://papiro.unizar.es/ojs/index.php/jji3a/article/download/1794/1608) the title mentions femto but the abstract is pico. In [this video](https://www.ted.com/talks/ramesh_raskar_a_camera_that_takes_one_trillion_frames_per_second) the presenter talks of a one-trillionth of second photography (pico), and says a pico is "a few" femto. And the video is titled femtophotography. In [this article](https://www.osapublishing.org/ao/viewmedia.cfm?uri=ao-10-9-2162&seq=0)  which is from 46 years ago I see the abstract of a pico-photography study. The title and description match here.

Comment: Is perhaps one in reference to time in seconds and the other in reference to distance in meters?

Answer (score 1):

I can only speculate here because the reasons for naming choices are known only to the namer, especially when it comes to promoting a technique. But I'll mention that "pico" often refers to many picoseconds, and likewise "femto" often refers to many femtoseconds. It seems a little disingenuous to promote a technique as "femto" when the frame rate is larger than a picosecond. But it may be that since they are (likely) imaging the propagation of a femtosecond laser, they feel justified, even if the streak camera ultimately has a slower time resolution.

As far as I can tell, these techniques are based on streak cameras, and usually the time resolutions (i.e. frame rate) for those are around 1 ps.